# Showing ImportError: cannot import name 'Message' from 'can' in my Ubuntu

Tags: linux, python

In my laptop Ubuntu 20, I am using TCP sockets for sending and receiving messages in `Python` and I am using `can` library. So the line in my python code here is:

```
from can import Message
```

It was working fine but then I changed the folders and then I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafi/PycharmProjects/Right Turn/CAN_simulator_Recv.py", line 12, in <module>
    from can import Message
ImportError: cannot import name 'Message' from 'can' (/home/rafi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/can/__init__.py)
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Maybe it has something to do with directory or packages? The same `can` library is working fine in my Raspberry Pi Ubuntu 20. Will reinstalling the laptop's Ubuntu help?

I installed it with the below command

```
pip3 install python-can
```

Tried uninstalling using the below command

```
pip3 uninstall python-can
```

But after trying to uninstall, it showed below error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Comment: Maybe [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) may be a better place to ask?

Comment: I asked here because I thought this library is only for Linux and I installed it via Ubuntu terminal but unable to uninstall also, don't know why.

Comment: How did you install it? How did you try to uninstall it? What is the actual name of this library? What did you change on your system? Exact answers please. Edit your question and include this information.

Comment: I have included the information

Comment: Try `pip3 uninstall python-can --user`.

Comment: A weird thing happened. After starting my laptop, Ubuntu seems fresh installed by itself and now the `python-can` library is working!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that worked for me:

1. Try `pip3 uninstall python-can` but with "sudo" permissions. Raspberry Pi will work this out, but Ubuntu asks your password one time:

   ```sh
   sudo pip3 uninstall python-can
   ```
2. To reinstall, don't use "sudo" again, then the lib will not have the right permissions to run. Instead, try without "sudo":

   ```sh
   pip3 install python-can
   ```

Now it worked for me. Hope it does for you as well...